# Joining 2 tables in C# Access Database

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, ms-access, oledb

I am creating a booking system for a university project and I'm trying to generate an invoice based off of different customers' bookings. I have a Bookings table and a Guests table within an Access database and I'm trying to find a way to merge these tables together using a Command from within my Connections class. Is there anyway to do a JOIN statement? I have a BookingID inside Bookings and a BookingsID_FK within Guests so that way there is at least some basic link.

Here is the first part of my connection class

```
    //Facade Class made to handle all connection's to Access Database properties
public class ConnectionClass
{
    OleDbConnection connection;
    OleDbCommand command;

    private void ConnectTo()
    {
        connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\MarkB\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Holiday_Reservation\Holiday_Reservation\Reservations.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
        command = connection.CreateCommand();
    }

    public ConnectionClass()
    {
        ConnectTo();
    }
```

Am I right in thinking that I would use a statement such as...

```
try
{

command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Bookings JOIN Guests ON Bookings.BookingID = Guests.BookingID_FK;"
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
connection.Open();

OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExcecuteReader();

    While (reader.Read())
    {


    DO SOMETHING......
```

Comment: out of curiosity have you thought of using SQL Server Express for your UNI work. Its free and has a all of the functionality that you would need

Comment: I'm afraid I am restricted to using all the features that came with Visual Studio Community edition. I'm not allowed any helpers like that :/

Comment: take a look at working with localDB then if you can, this should be able to give you all the SQL features you'd need too.  As you can probably tell im not a fan of MS Access :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic form of your SELECT statement is correct, except that Access SQL does not support an unqualified `JOIN` keyword. You'll need to use `INNER JOIN` (or possibly `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`).